# Laravel 9 Typescript not compiling files in public folder

Tags: typescript, laravel, laravel-9

I started up a new Laravel 9 project, installed typescript, and changed my vite.config.js file to direct to app.ts instead of app.js. This all worked and runs, but when I try to link '/public/js/index.ts' script file into one of my views, it throws the following error:

Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/index.ts' because its MIME type ('video/mp2t') is not executable.

By clicking on the file link, I can clearly see that it is being loaded by the browser, and if I just change the file from .ts to .js, everything works as intended, so it must be an issue with TypeScript not compiling my file, though I don't know why.
Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "es2020",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "strict": true,                 
      "skipLibCheck": true,           
      "noImplicitAny": false,          
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    },
    "include": ["/public/js/**/*", "/resources/js/**/*"],  
  }
```

Edit: Added vite.config.js file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/scss/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.ts'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    resolve:{
        alias: {
            "$": "jQuery"
        },

    }
});
```

Comment: how's your vite config? It seems to be trying to push the .ts file directly to the browser rather than transpiling it

Comment: @apokryfos I added the vite.config.js file, is there anything here that might cause such an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out:

I had my `index.ts` file inside `/public/js/`, when I put it in `/resources/js` and imported it using `@vite`, everything worked normally!